# JAX-WS Endpoint Serve arbitrary data from String xml

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

Is it possible to serve arbitrary data from an xml String in an endpoint, without the need for unmarshalling/creation of classes?

eg.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "java.somewhere")
public class MyService {   
    @Override
    public JAXBElement<?> getOrderData(String id) {
        String response = "<note>
                               <to>Tove</to>
                               <from>Jani</from>
                               <heading>Reminder</heading>
                               <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                           </note>";

        return response; //how?                       
    }
}
```